# Would the sentence be okay without the 'it'?

Tags: pronouns, cleft-constructions

> I still can't get **it** out of my mind, how she reacted to it all the other day.
>
> I still can't get out of my mind how she reacted to it all the other day.

Are both these sentences grammatically correct?
Is inserting the **it** in the sentence necessary?

Comment: You should have said "without the 'it' and without the comma".

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but the first sentence sounds natural to me although you need to take out the comma. Actually it sounds like a clever sentence like _She doesn’t like it when you are so quiet_. _**it**_ in your first sentence acts as an _**empty**_ object since your object is too long and it sounds awkward to say _I still can't get **how she reacted to it all the other day** out of my mind. You put _it_ there to fill in the object place which **anticipates the real object** at the end of your sentence.

Comment: To this native speaker, the version with **it** sounds incorrect.  Either *it* or *how she reacted* is the object of the sentence, but it doesn't really make sense to repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

> *I still can’t get how she reacted to it all the other day out of my mind.*

That’s a version without the ‘it’. However, I think it reads awkwardly, because there is so much between the *get* and the *out of my mind*.

A good way to remedy this is to use the ‘it’, as you did in the sentence in your question. However, I might punctuate it using a dash:

> *I still can't get it out of my mind – how she reacted to it all the other day*.

Your second sentence could be improved, I think by removing the *to it all*; it adds little meaning and clutters up the sentence:

> *I still can't get out of my mind how she reacted the other day.*

Answer (score 0):

> I still can't get it out of my mind, how she reacted to it all the
>   other day.
>
> I still can't get out of my mind how she reacted to it all the other
>   day.

Both are grammatical and idiomatic. In the first, the *how*-clause is an adjunct, apposite "it". In the second, the *how*-clause is a complement.

With the verb phrase "to get {something} out of one's mind", and others like it, it is legit to move the {something} out of the phrase and into a complement when that something is not a simple direct object, like "hat", but a clause:

> I couldn't get out of my mind her hat. <sup>odd, like "Throw mama from the train a kiss"</sup>
>
> I couldn't get her hat out of my mind. <sup>normal</sup>
>
> I couldn't get out of my mind how she insisted on wearing that hat.<sup>normal</sup>
>
> I couldn't get it out of my mind—how she insisted on wearing that hat.<sup>normal, the cleft emphasizing that which it was difficult to forget</sup>